# Применение преобразования к каждому элементу массива

Tags: javascript

**Стартовый код:**

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} arr
 * @param {Function} fn
 * @return {number[]}
 */

var map = function(arr, fn) {

};
```

**Задача:**
Задан целочисленный массив arr и функция fn, верните новый массив, к каждому элементу которого применено преобразование.

Возвращаемый массив должен быть создан таким образом, чтобы returnedArray[i] = fn(arr[i], i).

Пожалуйста, решите эту задачу без встроенного метода Array.map.

Пример 1:
Вход: arr = [1,2,3], fn = function plusone(n) { return n + 1; }
Выход: [2,3,4]
Пояснение:
const newArray = map(arr, plusone); // [2,3,4]
Функция увеличивает каждое значение в массиве на единицу.

Пример 2:
Вход: arr = [1,2,3], fn = function plusI(n, i) { return n + i; }
Выход: [1,3,5]
Пояснения: Функция увеличивает каждое значение на индекс, в котором оно находится.

Пример 3:
Вход: arr = [10,20,30], fn = function constant() { return 42; }
Выход: [42,42,42]
Пояснение: Функция всегда возвращает 42.

**Проблема** в том, что код ниже (мое решение) в обычном компиляторе выдает нужный результат, но на самом leetcode в кейсе
`function plusI(n, i) { return n + i; }` почему-то происходит конкатенация вместо суммирования.
Это с leetcode  проблема или я чего-то не понимаю?

```js
let plusone = function(arr) {
  return ++arr;
}

let plusI = function(n, i) {
  return parseInt(n) + parseInt(i);
};



let constant = function() {
  return 42;
}


var map = function(arr, fn) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i in arr) {
    result.push(fn(arr[i], i)); // Apply the function to each element and store the result in the new array
  }
  return result;
};

let arr = [1, 2, 3]
const newArray = map(arr, plusI);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что выражения `return n + i;` и `return parseInt(n) + parseInt(i);` не равны друг другу?

Comment: *Ссылка на задачу сверху.* Так не делают, вопрос должен быть самодостаточным. Добавьте условие решаемой задачи в текст вопроса.

Comment: Наверное в задаче указано откуда берутся данные и что они, наверное, могут быть не только числами, но и строками (эмитация ввода в html форму)

Comment: @Akina, переделал. Так годится?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, отредактировал вопрос. Здесь все условия, которые были. О return n + i; и return parseInt(n) + parseInt(i); понимаю.

Comment: Проблема в том, что `i` в for  строковая получается)) Сейчас может профи объяснят почему. Я хз))

Comment: Видимо потому, что массив - это объект.... а в объектах доступ через квадратные скобки к свойствам возможен только через стринговый ключ.... то вот такая логика

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо <3 . Да, оказалось так и есть. Суть в том, что на leetcode компилятор почему-то игнорирует  parseInt()  Number() и делает конкатенацию, при этом онлайн компилятор и компилятор в браузере спокойно выдают правильный результат и с for (let i in arr).

Comment: Можно писать `result.push(fn(arr[i], +i));`  либо через обычный `for (let i = 0 ...)`